# python cant install pycodestyle

Tags: python, permissions

im trying to install autopep8 using pip install. I am getting a permission denied when its trying to install pycodestyle

```html
Collecting autopep8
  Using cached autopep8-1.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycodestyle>=2.3 (from autopep8)
  Using cached pycodestyle-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pycodestyle, autopep8
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pycodestyle.py'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a problem with `python` but with your user's permissions on the `linux` box.
Try `sudo pip install package` instead of just `pip install package`.

Comment: Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it helped.